# Hardhat: which file is initial state in? Such as the mnemonic and 20 accounts?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Hardhat Network is initialized by default in this state:

A brand new blockchain, just with the genesis block.
20 accounts with 10000 ETH each, generated with the mnemonic "test test test test test test test test test test test junk". Their addresses are:
0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8
0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC
0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906
0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65
0x9965507D1a55bcC2695C58ba16FB37d819B0A4dc
0x976EA74026E726554dB657fA54763abd0C3a0aa9
0x14dC79964da2C08b23698B3D3cc7Ca32193d9955
0x23618e81E3f5cdF7f54C3d65f7FBc0aBf5B21E8f
0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720
0xBcd4042DE499D14e55001CcbB24a551F3b954096
0x71bE63f3384f5fb98995898A86B02Fb2426c5788
0xFABB0ac9d68B0B445fB7357272Ff202C5651694a
0x1CBd3b2770909D4e10f157cABC84C7264073C9Ec
0xdF3e18d64BC6A983f673Ab319CCaE4f1a57C7097
0xcd3B766CCDd6AE721141F452C550Ca635964ce71
0x2546BcD3c84621e976D8185a91A922aE77ECEc30
0xbDA5747bFD65F08deb54cb465eB87D40e51B197E
0xdD2FD4581271e230360230F9337D5c0430Bf44C0
0x8626f6940E2eb28930eFb4CeF49B2d1F2C9C1199
To customise it, take a look at the configuration section.

I want to find them in the config, but i dont know where r they

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#config) are the config options for the hardhat network. You should customize the `accounts` parameter.

It can be either:

> An object describing an HD wallet. This is the default. It can have
> any of the following fields:
>
> `mnemonic`: as defined by BIP39. Default value: "test test test test test test
> test test test test test junk"
>
> `initialIndex`: The initial index to
> derive. Default value: 0.
>
> `Default value`: "m/44'/60'/0'/0".
>
> `count`: The number of accounts to
> derive. Default value: 20.
>
> `accountsBalance`: string with the balance
> (in wei) assigned to every account derived. Default value:
> "10000000000000000000000" (10000 ETH).
>
> `passphrase`: The passphrase for
> the wallet. Default value: empty string.

In this case, all the default accounts are generated by the "test test ... junk" mnemonic phrase. You can use another mnemonic phrase for account generation or use your own private keys by specifying:

> An array of the initial accounts that the Hardhat Network will create. Each of them must be an
> object with privateKey and balance fields.

Hope it helps, happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I want to find their storage location in the hardhat configuration file. I believe these default contents are written in the hardhat file, but I can't find the storage location of these default contents

Comment: It is not. They are generated by the "test test...junk" mnemonic phrase. A mnemonic phrase can generate many private keys for many accounts.

Comment: the default mnemonics should also have a storage location. I want to know this location

Comment: It is probably hardcoded as the default value.

Comment: it is in main/packages/hardhat-core/src/internal/core/config/default-config.ts. Github: https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/blob/main/packages/hardhat-core/src/internal/core/config/default-config.ts

Comment: thanks for your help! i have found it!

Answer (score 1):

I can't ensure what are you looking for, but I can give you some infos:

- There are 2 common networks, we usually use for developing & testing when using hardhat on local are `hardhat` and `localhost
- 20 accounts that you see are initialized accounts on the hardhat network, you don't need to customize them, just use them.
- You could try `localhost` network by running a localhost node by `npx hardhat node`, they will show 20 account with addresses, private keys, balances too. Here it is: [image: hardhat node]
- Here is an example hardhat config:

```
module.exports = {
...,
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
    },
    hardhat: {
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
    },
    polygonMumbai: {
      url: "https://matic-mumbai.chainstacklabs.com",
      chainId: 80001,
      accounts: ['your_private_key1', 'your_private_key2']
    },
  }
}
```

- You can customize, put your private key wallet in `accounts`.
- You can run your scripts with a specified network by defining network, default is hardhat.

```
npx hardhat run script.js --network polygonMumbai
```

*Hope it help*

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I want to find their storage location in the hardhat configuration file. I believe these default contents are written in the hardhat file, but I can't find the storage location of these default contents